# How to Clone items on Click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, local-storage

I create some elements with local storage and it works fine but I want that items also should be cloned to a specific div tag.

here is my jsFidddle Code [jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pikitemplates/8kws0qyu/3/)

Now When I try to clone all element to `<div class="all-items"></div>` but it didn't work
here is my code below

```
 $(function() {
  $('.mix').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected')
    window.localStorage.setItem('test' + this.dataset.id, $(this).hasClass('selected'));
  });

  $('.mix').each(function() {
    var id = 'test' + this.dataset.id;
    if (localStorage.getItem(id) && localStorage.getItem(id) == "true") {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
        });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var e = $('.top-items');
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      e.clone().insertAfter(e);
    }
});
```

and the HTML is here

```
<div class="top-items">
<div data-id="1" class="box p001 mix ">Div 1</div>
<div data-id="2" class="box p002 mix">Div 2</div>
<div data-id="3" class="box p002 mix">Div 2</div>
<div data-id="4" class="box p002 mix">Div 2</div>
<div data-id="5" class="box p002 mix">Div 2</div>
</div>

<div class="all-items"></div> //all elements should be clone here on click one by one
```

To achieve this i try on click function but it didn't give perfect solution so that i want when elements added they should be remove onclick from this `<div class="all-items"></div>` cloned tag.

any help or advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: There seems to be no reference to `$(".all-items")` in your code.   "*but it didn't give perfect solution*" - please include your attempt.  It's unclear if the localStorage is relevant to the cloning issue; if it's not relevant, then there's no need to include it.

Comment: Note: in your fiddle, it's `<div class="all items">` that's *two*, separate classes.

Comment: Where's the code that clones the elements? I don't see it here on Stack Overflow. Please use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to share a [mre] of the code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please re-check i updated the code and jsFiddle both

Comment: If you want them in `all-items` then you should insert *into* all-items `e.clone().appendTo(".all-items");`  https://jsfiddle.net/bLs6vyuq/1/

Comment: Regarding the click - `$(".mix").click(...` will only be applied to elements with class "mix" that exist *at the time the code runs* - so you don't need to "remove the click event" on the new elements as it won't exist.   Event delegation is required when you *do* want the click events on new elements.

Comment: It's a little unclear what your issue is, to be honest.   "*didn't give perfect solution*" / "*didn't work*" - without knowing what you *expect* it's hard to tell you why it's not doing that.

Comment: i just want to clone all items but by using onclick so that when user click on element it should be cloned below also when user click on cloned item It show be removed

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].  You need to ask a clear, specific question that provides what you want.  In some cases *small* follow-on questions in comments are acceptable.  Writing your application for you, step-by-step is not acceptable.

Comment: please i need the answer that you removed kindly give me the code again

Comment: Apologies, forgot you can't see deleted answers: https://jsfiddle.net/rjs6kzuo/

Comment: Also, previous comment: If you want it moved don't use .clone(). You already have code for local storage. If you only want 1 copy then use event delegation on the copy and remove the/a class so that it can't be added. When removing you'll need to re-add that class so you'll need a way to know which is being removed - you already have that with data-id.

Comment: can you provide working code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
let topItemsHTML = $(".top-items").html()
$(".top-items").html("");  // clear top-items div

$(".all-items").html(topItemsHTML)  // fill all-items with top-items
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  There's no need to use `.html()` to move elements.  OP is trying to (or appears to be) create a copy by using `.clone()` so "clear top-items" would not be appropriate.  To *move* elements, you can just use `$(".top-items>div").appendTo(".all-items")`.

Comment: please can you provide any jsFiddle working solution

Comment: @riya875 you haven't specified what you would consider a "working solution" - with a minor change, your code "works", but it's not clear if it "works perfectly" as there's no detail as to what it *should* do: https://jsfiddle.net/bLs6vyuq/1/